# Ubuntu 18.04 asking for password after the new installation

Tags: login, 18.04

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 newly and after the installation it is asking for a password. But I have not set up any password, I did fresh install only.

[image]

SO what should I do to login?

Comment: Maybe you left it blank during installation? If a blank password doesn't work (shouldn't) then reinstall and fill in a proper password.

Comment: have you tried root , toor or ubuntu

Comment: Setting a password is part of the installation process. It will be asked [directly after giving your user name](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/es6-bundled/src/codelabs/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop/img/6a5c43ee70b5a049.png). As you have obviously chosen one, you have also set a password. You might have confused that for something else.

Comment: If you can't remember the password selected during system installation you can refer to [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](/q/24006/175814)